# woocommerce lost password is showing blank page

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords, woocommerce, endpoint

I am trying to get the lost password page to work on woocommerce but when I click on the "lost your password?" link I get redirected to the lost password page, but nothing is on the page.

I've made a lost password page: www.example.com/lost-password/
lost password endpoint: /lost-password/

my guess is I need to copy the form-lost-password.php but I cant find where.
any help?
thanks

Comment: If you are getting a completely blank page, then you should consider turning on [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG). If you aren't getting any content (but headers, menus, footers, etc still show) then maybe your theme's lost password template is out of date. You see which templates are out of date in the WooCommerce system settings and test removing them all by renaming your theme's `woocommerce` folder temporarily.